# Can Google My Business Questions & Answers be managed from mobile devices?

Tags: google-my-business

I am aware the Q&A for GMB is now available on mobile devices.

While no one has asked our business a question yet, I cannot see any tab for this within the Google My Business interface in order to manage them (like you can for reviews). Does this only appear when you have questions on your location?

Answer (score 1):

You can answer customer questions using the Google Maps App for Android:

https://www.en.advertisercommunity.com/t5/News-Updates/Answer-customer-questions-on-Google-Maps-for-Android/m-p/1191452#